# What's the cleanest way to do case-insensitive parsing with Text.Combinators.Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm writing my first program with Parsec. I want to parse MySQL schema dumps and would like to come up with a nice way to parse strings representing certain keywords in case-insensitive fashion. Here is some code showing the approach I'm using to parse "CREATE" or "create". Is there a better way to do this? An answer that doesn't resort to buildExpressionParser would be best. I'm taking baby steps here.

```
  p_create_t :: GenParser Char st Statement
  p_create_t = do
      x <- (string "CREATE" <|> string "create")
      xs <- manyTill anyChar (char ';')
      return $ CreateTable (x ++ xs) []  -- refine later
```

Comment: I'm assuming that `map toLower` on the input before even running the parser isn't an option? Also, I'd expect "case insensitive" to also match "Create", "CrEaTe", "CREATe", or any other variation, which your example rejects. Which do you want?

Comment: That does work. Thanks. I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: @dan Just beware that if your input contains strings, they'll be lowercased too. For example, if any of your columns contain default string values.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can build the case-insensitive parser out of character parsers.

```
-- Match the lowercase or uppercase form of 'c'
caseInsensitiveChar c = char (toLower c) <|> char (toUpper c)

-- Match the string 's', accepting either lowercase or uppercase form of each character 
caseInsensitiveString s = try (mapM caseInsensitiveChar s) <?> "\"" ++ s ++ "\""
```

Answer (score 9):

Repeating what I said in a comment, as it was apparently helpful:

The simple sledgehammer solution here is to simply map `toLower` over the entire input before running the parser, then do all your keyword matching in lowercase.

This presents obvious difficulties if you're parsing something that needs to be case-insensitive in some places and case-sensitive in others, or if you care about preserving case for cosmetic reasons. For example, although HTML tags are case-insensitive, converting an entire webpage to lowercase while parsing it would probably be undesirable. Even when compiling a case-insensitive programming language, converting identifiers could be annoying, as any resulting error messages would not match what the programmer wrote.

Answer (score 4):

No, Parsec cannot do that *in clean way*. `string` is implemented on top of
primitive `tokens` combinator that is hard-coded to use equality test
`(==)`. It's a bit simpler to parse case-insensitive character, but you
probably want more.

There is however a modern fork of Parsec, called
[Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) which has
built-in solutions for everything you may want:

```
λ> parseTest (char' 'a') "b"
parse error at line 1, column 1:
unexpected 'b'
expecting 'A' or 'a'
λ> parseTest (string' "foo") "Foo"
"Foo"
λ> parseTest (string' "foo") "FOO"
"FOO"
λ> parseTest (string' "foo") "fo!"
parse error at line 1, column 1:
unexpected "fo!"
expecting "foo"
```

Note the last error message, it's better than what you can get parsing
characters one by one (especially useful in your particular case). `string'`
is implemented just like Parsec's `string` but uses case-insensitive
comparison to compare characters. There are also `oneOf'` and `noneOf'` that
may be helpful in some cases.

---

*Disclosure*: I'm one of the authors of Megaparsec.

Comment: Indeed surprising that `tokens` does not allow a compare function to be passed to it to perform the comparison in the original Parsec.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping the entire input with `toLower`, consider using `caseString` from `Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Rfc2234` (from the hsemail package)

[Text.ParsecCombinators.Parsec.Rfc2234](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsemail-1.3/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-Rfc2234.html#1)

```
p_create_t :: GenParser Char st Statement
p_create_t = do
  x <- (caseString "create")
  xs <- manyTill anyChar (char ';')
  return $ CreateTable (x ++ xs) []  -- refine later
```

So now `x` will be whatever case-variant is present in the input without changing your input.

ps: I know that this is an ancient question, I just thought that I would add this as this question came up while I was searching for a similar problem

Comment: This is not from Text.ParsecCombinators.Parsec. It is from Text.ParsecCombinators.Parsec.Rfc2234. Your link is correct, but your title is wrong. Also of note is that that is part of the hsemail package, which someone might not already have installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package name parsec-extra for this purpuse. You need install this package then use  '*caseInsensitiveString*' parser.

```
 :m Text.Parsec
 :m +Text.Parsec.Extra

*> parseTest   (caseInsensitiveString  "values")   "vaLUES"
"values"

*> parseTest   (caseInsensitiveString  "values")   "VAlues"
"values"
```

Link to package is here:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-extra